# (Spotify iOS SDK) renewSession always return nil session

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am building a small app on iOS that uses the Spotify SDK in order to make requests to its Web Api. The thing is, I am using the function **`STPAuth.renewSession`** to renew the token whenever I want to make a request. But for that function  documentation says *'If no token refresh service has been specified the callback will return nil as session'.* And that's what is happening to me. I'm always getting a nil 'renewedSession' (https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTAuth.html#//api/name/renewSession:callback:)

I ve searched over there and found that this guy on this video uses a server that runs some script and he turns on using terminal, specifying a token refresh service URL on his app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE) but nothing of that appears mentioned on the Spotify's iOS SDK tutorial..

How is that specifically done? Or Maybe there is an alternative way..

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the Authorization Code Flow. A description of the concept can be found here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow. In order for your app to send a session refresh request, you'll need a service of some sort to make the request on your behalf. You can use Node.js, with the caveat that it violates OAuth 2.0 standards. There is a nice explanation and setup for a Node.js token swap service URL that can be deployed to Heroku here: https://github.com/rorygilchrist/node-spotify-token-swap

Once you have your service set up, inside your app you'll have to handle the callback URL and then call SPTAuth.renewSession to trigger the request.

Comment: Spotify wants me to build a server so I can use their goddamned api to refresh a freaking token that only lasts 1 hour... This is the worst api ever made, this is a shame to mankind.

Comment: It's standard architecture for any service using OAuth 2.0, not just Spotify.